# TFS ALM and Referencing the Correct Branch

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, alm

I hope you can help me with my problem.
I currently have a solution in Visual Studio 2013 that houses 4 projects. We are using Team Foundation Server 2013 for version control and we're starting to get into Lifecycle Management.

My solution looks like:
Solution
-Framework
-Unit Tests
-Web API
-MVC Web Application

Each of our TFS Projects are set up with three branches, /Development, /Test, /Production. All but the Framework are in one /Development branch. The Framework is being referenced from its own TFS Project's /Development branch.

I'm planning on merging my Framework changes into its /Test branch, then, I will merge my Web API project into its /Test branch.

How do I make sure the Web API /Test branch is referencing the Frameworks /Test branch? All of this is so when we publish to our test server, we know we are referencing the correct version of the framework.

I know I can edit the solution file in notepad to manually make this change, but, there has to be an easier way. What would that 'easier way' be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you should have one set of branches, and within a branch is all 4 projects.  This way you just branch/merge the entire solution.